# Why this script doesn't work in C# properly, while it's working in PowerShell ISE

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint

I want to run a `PowerShell` script to get `ContentType`(s) of a list via C#.
In the PowerShell the following script works:

```
$list.ContentTypes[0].Name
```

I want to have same result when I'm running it in C# as follows:

```
powershell.AddScript(string.Format("$web = Get-SPWeb {0}", testWeb));
powershell.AddScript("$web.Lists");
var psObjects = powershell.Invoke();

foreach (var psObject in psObjects)
{
    var currentList = (dynamic)psObject;
    powershell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("list", psObject);
    powershellContentTypes.AddScript("$list.ContentTypes");
    var psContentTypes = powershellContentTypes.Invoke();

    foreach (dynamic psContentType in psContentTypes)
    {
        // I expect to psContentType to have Name property.
        // But its properties are like string.
        var name = psContentType.Name
    }
}
```

But, unforunately, the `psContentType` has not any `Name` property. All of returned `psContentTypes` are of type `string` with this value: "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType"

What's wrong with my script in C#?

Comment: Can you test this in a new powershell session not using the ISE. Part of the environment can persist between your script executions in ISE. Running it from a new shell might explain a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Since [PSObject Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Management.Automation.PSObject(v=vs.85).aspx) *encapsulates* a base object, in that case [SPContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.aspx), you could consider the following options to access object properties:

1. Access base object via [PSObject.BaseObject Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject.baseobject(v=vs.85).aspx)

   ```
   var contentType = psContentType.BaseObject as SPContentType;
   var contentTypeName = contentType.Name;
   ```
2. Use [PSObject.Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject.members(v=vs.85).aspx) to access base object properties, for
   example to retrieve Content Type Name:

   ```
   var contentTypeName = psContentType.Members["Name"].Value;
   ```

### Modified example

```
using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
   powershell.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell");
   powershell.AddScript(string.Format("$web = Get-SPWeb {0}", webUrl));
   powershell.AddScript("$web.Lists");
   var psLists = powershell.Invoke();

   foreach (var psList in psLists)
   {
       powershell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("list", psList);
       powershell.AddScript("$list.ContentTypes");
       var psContentTypes = powershell.Invoke();

       foreach (var psContentType in psContentTypes)
       {
          //var contentType = psContentType.BaseObject as SPContentType;
          //var name = contentType.Name;


          var type = psContentType.BaseObject.GetType();
          if (type.Name == "SPContentType")
          {
              var contentTypeName = psContentType.Members["Name"].Value;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I don't want to reference to SharePoint libraries. So casting to `SPContentType`. Also the second solution doesn't work and throws `NullReferenceException`. I checked the `Members`, it has values like `Split, SubString, Length, ...` which is like `string`'s properties.